# Remove characters from a cell with imported API data in Google Sheets - or format api import

Tags: json, api, rest, google-sheets

I'll start by saying that my knowledge on using APIs is extremely limited. I'm impressed I've gotten as far as I have on this.

I've created a workbook in Google Sheets with imported data from the [iexcloud API](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/), which I'm using for data on stocks.

The requests have a cell reference in them so they update whenever a different symbol is selected.

So far, everything I've needed to request from it has the option to format as csv, so I can get cells with just the values.

However, this last thing I want doesn't have that option, so the whole response is wrapped in ["" ].

That really messes up what I need it for.

Here's an example

> ["PSA"    CCI SHO ACC]

with each symbol being in its own cell.

I'm using the [Peer Groups request](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#peer-groups).

A sample request:

```
> https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/peers?token=Tsk_2b4c7c6fd98542f6a99f904cb7a3e721
```

Using Find and Replace doesn't work. I'm assuming because it's imported.

I need to use the cells with those symbols: PSA, CCI, SHO, ACC to reference in another request.

I recreated this in another Google Sheet that you can edit. The section in question in highlighted in blue

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BQ6FBD0S2YkDtDGZGIkDmQoKrQT4VmVDjuNsgV4mrXM/edit?usp=sharing

So I'm wondering if there's a way to have [ " ] automatically removed from any cells in that row, or if I copy and paste the values only, to have the values updated when the original cells are updated with new symbols (since I can have those characters removed in that row)

Or if there's a way I can format the response in sheets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve from `["CCI"  SBAC    CTL TDS RCI RCI-A-CT    DTEGY]` to `CCI SBAC    CTL TDS RCI RCI-A-CT    DTEGY` using the built-in functions of Google Spreadsheet.

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTDATA("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/"&B3&"/peers?format=psv&token=###"),"[\[\]""]",""))
```

- In this modified formula, `[`, `]` and `"` are removed using `REGEXREPLACE`.
- Please replace `###` with your token at the above formula.

#### Result:

In this result, the values retrieved with `=IMPORTDATA("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/"&B3&"/peers?format=psv&token=###")` are used. So the formula of cell "C9" is `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(C6:I6,"[\[\]""]",""))`. But in this case, above modified formula can be used.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this answer, I removed your token because I thought that it is your personal information.

#### Reference:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! And thanks for the consideration on the token. I appreciate that. I voted up your answer, but since I'm new it won't show on here. Thank you!